# graphql error: mutation with where not working

Tags: schema, graphql, mutation, prisma

I am using Prisma GraphqQL and I got this error for a mutation with where selector: 
"You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on User"

Mutation:

```
mutation UpdateUserMutation($data: UserUpdateInput!, $where: UserWhereUniqueInput!) {
  updateUser(data: $data, where: $where) {
    id
    name
    email
    role
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "alan", "email": "alan@gmail.com", "role": "ADMIN"
  },
  "where": {
    "id": "cjfsvcaaf00an08162sacx43i"
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateUser": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on User.",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [
        "updateUser"
      ],
      "code": 3040,
      "requestId": "api:api:cjftyj8ov00gi0816o4vvgpm5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema:

```
updateUser(
  data: UserUpdateInput!
  where: UserWhereUniqueInput!
): User


type UserWhereUniqueInput {
  id: ID
  resetPasswordToken: String
  email: String
}
```

Why this mutation is not working?

With colors:
Mutation GraphQL
[image: Mutation GraphQL]
Schema Graphql
[image: Schema Graphql]

---

**EXTRA INFORMATION**

*Full code* of this Project is [here](https://github.com/alan345/naperg):

*Graphql playground* is [here](https://graphqlbin.com/Lg0Wfm):

*Console view* (variable are empty):
[image: console view (variable are empty):]

*Query for user* (with id: cjfsvcaaf00an08162sacx43i). So user can be found with "where" operator in query, but not in mutation.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updateUser resolver is not implemented correctly:

```
async function updateUser(parent, { id, name, email, role }, ctx, info) {
   // console.log( id, name, email)
  await ctx.db.mutation.updateUser({
    where: { id: id },
    data: {name: name, email: email, role: role},
  })
}
```

Your mutation has the two parameters data and where, but you expect the parameter list { id, name, email, role }.

Either update your schema, or your resolver accordingly.

Source: https://github.com/graphcool/prisma/issues/2211

Comment: You can mark your answer as solving the question :)

Comment: Yes :) I ll do that!